# Using c++20 modules with Visual Studio and Clang-cl 13

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, clang-cl

Recently, I tried to use modules with VS2022, Clang-cl-13. I followed the instructions I found. Enabled `std:c++latest` and `experimental:module`. Created a most-basic module file (`Module.ixx`):

```
export module Module;

export int MyFunc()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Imported it in another file and used it, and Clang gives me a `module 'Module' not found` error. The same program works when I switch the compiler to the MS compiler. Did I miss a step with Clang or are modules not supported yet?